# how to handle error from geocode (ggmap R)

Tags: r, google-geocoder, ggmap

I'm using ggmap to find locations. Some locations generates error. For example,

```
library(ggmap)

loc = 'Blue Grass Airport'
geocode(loc, output = c("more"))
```

results in

```
Error in data.frame(long_name = "Blue Grass Airport", short_name = "Blue Grass Airport",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

It's ok if I can't get results for some locations, but I'm trying to work on 100 locations in a list. So is there a way to get NA instead of error and keep things go on? E.g.,

```
library(ggmap)

loc = c('Blue Grass Airport', 'Boston MA', 'NYC')
geocode(loc, output = c("more"))
```

should generate

```
NA
Result for Boston
Result for New York City
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the R `tryCatch()` function to handle these errors gracefully:

```
loc = 'Blue Grass Airport'
x <- tryCatch(geocode(loc, output = c("more")),
              warning = function(w) {
                            print("warning"); 
                            # handle warning here
                        },
              error = function(e) {
                          print("error");
                          # handle error here
                      })
```

If you intend to loop over locations explicitly using a `for` loop or using an `apply` function, then `tryCatch()` should also come in handy.

Comment: Thank you@Tim Biegeleisen. Does this have to work with `for` or `apply`? Is there a way I can input a list `loc = c(loc1, loc2, loc3)`?

Comment: You can use `lapply(loc, function(x) { y <- tryCatch(geocode(x, output = c("more")), ...)`

Comment: For most things probably better to use `ggmap::geocode()`, but `taRifx.geo::geocode` has a `data.frame` method which automatically fills in only the `NA` observations and also uses `try` to trap errors and chug along anyway.